# Union of file contents?

Tags: merge, io

I'm trying to merge a whole bunch of files together.  Most of the files will have the same data on each line.  How can I merge them all together in one file so that the result is the union of all the lines of all the files?

What is a utility that can easily do this? Or some other quick way?

I use Windows.

Thanks!

Comment: When the data is not the same on each line, what do you want the output to be?  For example, each different line, concatenated together?  It might also be important to know if the order of the lines in each file is identical.

Comment: @Rob, If the lines are different, then they need to be added on separate lines in the result.  Hmm I'm thinking about the ordering.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to combine them, the. `copy` command should be able to do that.

```
copy *.txt combo.txt
```

You might also be able to use the `type` command.

```
type *.txt > combo.txt
```

If you need the combined file sorted, [there's a command for that](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sort.mspx), too.

But when you say "union," it makes me think that you want to remove duplicates.  I don't know how to do that in pure Windows, but standard Unix utilities were born for this stuff.  If you were to [install Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html), you could use those utilities for this kind of text manipulation without leaving Windows.  The command would look something like this:

```
cat *.txt | sort -u > combo.txt
```

Comment: Yeah I need to remove the duplicates.  Cool I think I will give Cygwin a shot.  Thanks